# Use both dropdown and inline completions for different types of completions

Tags: monaco-editor

I've got a project that uses Monaco for source code editing and has Intelllisense set up and working nicely using the normal dropdown.

I'd now like to *additionally* add inline suggestions from a different completion item provider. What's the easiest way to accomplish this?

The use-case is that I'd like to add github copilot style AI autocomplete that operates separately from the intellisense suggestions

I know I can configure completion items to be shown inline using this config:

```
      quickSuggestions: {
          "other": "inline",
          "comments": true,
          "strings": true
      },
```

But I only want to use the inline mode for my new AI completion suggestions.

I was expecting there to be some ability to configure this, either on a completion item or when registering the completion provider, but couldn't find any in the docs